# bash autocompletion of filename using option value

Tags: bash, autocomplete, filenames

This question is an extension of an existing question, [Autocomplete of filename in directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/autocomplete-of-filename-in-directory).  I have a command, [`gmtFoam`](https://github.com/hertzsprung/AtmosFOAM/wiki/gmtFoam), that expects to receive the name of a file located in `$PWD/constant/gmtDicts`.  I used [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28289/8018) to enable tab completion of these filename.

The `gmtFoam` command can be instructed to search in a location other than `$PWD` by using the `-case` option, for example

```
gmtFoam -case ~/anotherDir myFile
```

will look for a file `~/anotherDir/constant/gmtDicts/myFile`.  How can I extend the bash autocompletion function to look at the case directory if it is supplied, and default to `$PWD` if it is not?  The autocompletion should also fall back to the usual file/directory completion method when only `gmtFoam -case " has been typed

Comment: I just realised I erroneously posted this on SO rather than unix.se.  If it would be better migrated, then feel free to do so.

Comment: Your completion function is going to need to scan for the `-case` argument and its value and then use that to generate completions instead of using the default value. You have access to all the command line words in `COMP_WORDS` so you just need to scan them for what you need.